# updateItem/putItem object into array in dynamodb

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm having trouble pushing an object into an array/Set the object into it as docs state in dynamodb.
Getting the error:

```
Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect number of operands for operator or function; operator or function: if_not_exists, number of operands: 1
```

What am I doing wrong?
I appreciate any help!

```
   export async function postTrade(position) {
    let params = {
        Key: {
            PK: 'stocks' 
        },
        UpdateExpression: 'set #tickers = list_append(if_not_exists(#tickers))',
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            '#tickers': 'tickers'
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':tickers': [position]
        },
        TableName: 'stockTable'
    };
    await docClient.update(params).promise();
}
```

Dynamo record

```
{
 "PK": "stocks",
 "tickers": [
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Appending to a list

**`list_append` takes 2 parameters, not one:**

- `list_append (list1, list2)`
- The function takes two lists as input and appends all elements from `list2` to `list1`

### Checking an attribute exists

**Likewise, `if_not_exists()` takes 2 parameters:**

- `if_not_exists (path, value)`
- If the item does not contain an attribute at the specified path, `if_not_exists` evaluates to `value`; otherwise, it evaluates to `path`. Therefore, you should use an empty array as a parameter.

### Solution

Pass 2 parmeters to each function, which should allow you to append to a list.

```
    let params = {
        Key: {
            PK: 'stocks' 
        },
        UpdateExpression: 'set #tickers = list_append(if_not_exists(#tickers, :empty_list), :tickers)',
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            '#tickers': 'tickers'
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':tickers': [position],
            ':empty_list': []
        },
        TableName: 'stockTable'
    };
```